# why fragment not showing empty white screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am developing a news app and I have implemented ViewModel in fragment class and getting data in fragment class but it is loading progress bar only not showing data which coming from server

below My MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel(newsRepository: Any?) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
     val job = Job()
     val sportNewsInterface: SportNewsInterface? = null
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

     val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
     val sportList = MutableLiveData <List<Article>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()



    fun loadNews(

    ) {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                sportNewsInterface?.getNews()
            }
            // Hide progressBar once the operation is done on the MAIN (default) thread
            showLoading.value = false
            when (result) {

                is UseCaseResult.Success<*> -> {
                    sportList.value = result.data as List<Article>
                }
                is Error -> showError.value = result.message
            }
        }


    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        // Clear our job when the linked activity is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

below Adapter class

```
class TopHeadlinesAdapter(val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TopHeadlinesAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {



    private var articleList: List<Article> by Delegates.observable(emptyList()) { _, _, _ ->
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_list, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articleList.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.articleTitle.text = articleList.get(position).title
        holder.articleSourceName.text = articleList.get(position).source.name
        Picasso.get().load(articleList.get(position).urlToImage).into(holder.image)

        val input = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
        val output = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        var d = Date()
        try {
            d = input.parse(articleList[5].publishedAt)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            try {
                val fallback = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
                fallback.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
                d = fallback.parse(articleList[5].publishedAt)
            } catch (e2: ParseException) {
                // TODO handle error
                val formatted = output.format(d)
                val timelinePoint = LocalDateTime.parse(formatted)
                val now = LocalDateTime.now()

                var elapsedTime = Duration.between(timelinePoint, now)

                println(timelinePoint)
                println(now)
                elapsedTime.toMinutes()

                holder.articleTime.text = "${elapsedTime.toMinutes()}"

            }
        }

    }

    fun updateData(newList: List<Article>) {
        articleList = newList

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun example() {
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

        val image: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val articleTitle: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleTitle)
        val articleSourceName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleSourceName)
        val imageCategory: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageCategory)
        val articleTime: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleTime)

    }
}
```

below TopHeadlinesFragment where I have implemented ViewModel

```
class TopHeadlinesFragment : Fragment() {

     private var viewModel: MainViewModel? = null
    private lateinit var topHeadlinesAdapter: TopHeadlinesAdapter


    //3
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_top_headlines
            , container, false
        )


        val recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
        val pb = view.findViewById(R.id.pb) as ProgressBar
        topHeadlinesAdapter = TopHeadlinesAdapter(recyclerView.context)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.adapter = topHeadlinesAdapter
        initViewModel()

        return view
    }

    private fun initViewModel() {
        viewModel?.sportList?.observe(this, Observer { newList ->
            topHeadlinesAdapter.updateData(newList)
        })




        viewModel?.showLoading?.observe(this, Observer { showLoading ->
            pb.visibility = if (showLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE


            viewModel?.showError?.observe(this, Observer { showError ->
                (showError)
            })

            viewModel?.loadNews()
        })
    }
}
```

below AppModules.kt

```
const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"

val appModules = module {
    // The Retrofit service using our custom HTTP client instance as a singleton
    single {
        createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = BASE_URL
        )
    }
    // Tells Koin how to create an instance of CatRepository
    factory<NewsRepository> { (NewsRepositoryImpl(sportNewsInterface = get())) }
    // Specific viewModel pattern to tell Koin how to build MainViewModel
    viewModel { MainViewModel (newsRepository = get ())  }
}

/* Returns a custom OkHttpClient instance with interceptor. Used for building Retrofit service */
fun createHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    client.readTimeout(5 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return client.addInterceptor {
        val original = it.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        val request = requestBuilder.method(original.method, original.body).build()
        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(request)
    }.build()
}

/* function to build our Retrofit service */
inline fun <reified T> createWebService(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    factory: CallAdapter.Factory, baseUrl: String
): T {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(factory)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
}
```

below fragment_top_headlines.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

below news_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="bbc"
            tools:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="1\n2\n3\n" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageCategory"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_espn"
            tools:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleSourceName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageCategory"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageCategory"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="Onefootbal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/articleSourceName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/articleSourceName"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="- 1h"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            tools:ignore="NotSibling" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

below NewsRepository.kt

```
interface NewsRepository {
    // Suspend is used to await the result from Deferred
    suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>>
}

class NewsRepositoryImpl(private val sportNewsInterface: SportNewsInterface) : NewsRepository {
    override suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>> {
        /*
         We try to return a list of cats from the API
         Await the result from web service and then return it, catching any error from API
         */
        return try {
            val result = sportNewsInterface.getNews()
            UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>>
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            UseCaseResult.Error(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

below SportInterface.kt where I am getting ending points

```
interface SportNewsInterface {

    @GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
    suspend fun getNews(): List<SportNewsResponse>

    @GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=espn&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
    fun getEspn(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

    @GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=football-italia&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
    fun getFootballItalia(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

    @GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-sport&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
    fun getBBCSport(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>


}
```

below SportNewsResponse.kt

```
data class SportNewsResponse(
    val articles: List<Article>,
    val status: String,
    val totalResults: Int
)
```

below Article.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "news_table")
data class Article(@ColumnInfo(name = "author")val author: String,
                   val content: String,
                   val description: String,
                   val publishedAt: String,
                   val source: Source,
                   val title: String,
                   val url: String,
                   val urlToImage: String
)
```

Comment: From where you initialize your `viewModel`?

Comment: @Md. Asaduzamman I have followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@gunayadem.dev/boost-your-android-apps-with-koin-and-coroutines-using-mvvm-in-kotlin-d30fe436ab4c

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman there are not used viewmodelprovider

Comment: Then you have to use `private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModel()`. Tutorial doing same. You have missed it. right?

Comment: Please read tutorial carefully and try to understand logic instead of just copy-paste. Thanks

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman it is still showing white screen and there is no error on the logcat I am following tutorial whats your suggestion

Comment: Check my answer and let me know

Comment: @sashabeliy move all your initial code into `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`

Comment: @huang12345 can you explain what you mean with coding sample

Comment: @sashabeliy Check my answer

Comment: @haung12345 it is still showing white screen and I have checked logcat there is also no error or any exception

Answer (score 0):

Your `initViewModel` doesn't looks ok. Try using below:

```
private fun initViewModel() {
    viewModel?.sportList?.observe(this, Observer { newList ->
        topHeadlinesAdapter.updateData(newList)
    })

    viewModel?.showLoading?.observe(this, Observer { showLoading ->
        pb.visibility = if (showLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    })

    viewModel?.showError?.observe(this, Observer { showError ->
        (showError)
    })

    viewModel?.loadNews()
}
```

Comment: Asaduzzamman java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/koin/core/parameter/ParameterListKt;
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.ui.TopHeadlinesFragment.<init>(TopHeadlinesFragment.kt:90)
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:24)

Answer (score 0):

**First** viewModel should not be null, use `lateinit` and init viewModel while fragment is created.

**Second** you dont need to use `findViewById` because you are using Kotlin.
So you can move all your initial view  into `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`

**Third** initialize viewModel by `viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)`
or just `viewModel = MainViewModel()`. That make your viewModel works.

After all, I dont know the `newsRepository` meaning in your MainModel. You never use it, maybe you can delete it.

```
class TopHeadlinesFragment : Fragment() {

   private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
   private lateinit var topHeadlinesAdapter: TopHeadlinesAdapter

   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater,
       container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {
       val view = inflater.inflate(
           R.layout.fragment_top_headlines
           , container, false
       )

       return view
   }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

       topHeadlinesAdapter = TopHeadlinesAdapter(context)
       recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
       recyclerView.adapter = topHeadlinesAdapter

       initViewModel()

       viewModel.loadNews()
   }

   private fun initViewModel() {

       viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

       viewModel?.sportList?.observe(this, Observer { newList ->
           topHeadlinesAdapter.updateData(newList)
       })

       viewModel?.showLoading?.observe(this, Observer { showLoading ->

           pb.visibility = if (showLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

           viewModel?.showError?.observe(this, Observer { showError ->
               (showError)
           })
       })
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is still showing white screen and there also not error on the logcat